# Почему проекты Rust так много весят?

Tags: rust

Я создал проект на **Rust**, добавил в него библиотеку [bevy](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy) и теперь проект весит несколько гигабайт.

Почему в **Rust** так много весят библиотеки и как сжать их?

Comment: Гигабайт? Я сегодня ровно на это попался, но у меня дебаг и релиз по размеру не отличались...

Comment: речь про размер финального релиного бинаря, отладочного бинаря или target директории?

Comment: https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ очень простой: **статическая линковка**.

Собранный на RUST проект представляет собой один бинарник, который будет одинаково запускаться в разных системах (ну, внутри линукса - линксовый, внутри винды - виндовый, но при этом на версию OS и набор установленных библиотек им будет напревать)

В обычном состоянии нет необходимости собирать программу так, чтобы всё необходимое было статически прилинковано. То есть, маленькая программка, запустившись в целевой системе, находит и подгружает в память множество DLL'ек, или их аналогов - либов - из мира линукс.

Вы можете провеси подобный эксперимент с C++: взять простую программу, что то чуть чуть посложнее hello world. И собрать её с ключем --static. У меня, в примере, в котором использовалась работа со строками и файловой системой, размер exe шника под винду с легкостью добрался примерно до 15 мегабайт.